# Process Builder Scheduled Action - will the schedule update if it's based on a date on a parent Record?

Tags: process-builder, scheduled

I've got a scheduled action that sends an email a day after a date that is managed on a field on a parent record to the record that fires the process. To further complicate it, one of the criteria to fire the action references the date field on the parent record as well.

My question is: if I update the date on the parent record, will the action reschedule? I have two concerns:

- Because the date isn't recorded/updated on the record firing the process, the schedule won't reevaluate
- Because the date is also used in the criteria (and the action is set to fire only when specified changes are made to the record), updating the field from one date that already meets the criteria to another won't cause the process to refire (since the record already met the criteria) and this will prevent the schedule from updating

**Update**
Here's a screenshot of the criteria using the Date field and the Scheduled Action

Criteria (gets the Parent's Date field by dot notation):
[image]
Scheduled Action (forgot to mention that the Scheduled Action is actually scheduled on a Formula referencing the Parent's Date)
[image]

Comment: Hi bswift - welcome to SFSE. Exactly how are you referencing the parent date field in the scehdule action criteria? Please use [edit] and post a screen shot for the scheduled action

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Added screenshots and some notes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the parent date field changes, it won't alter the original schedule unless/until the child is modified. The solution to this is to set up a process on the parent object to update the matching child object when the field changes. This will allow the reschudling to happen. As far as the date changing, as long as the child meets the criteria still, and the date changes, it should cause the action to be rescheduled to the new date.

Comment: note also that using cross-object formula field on the child that references the parent object's date field will not work; one has to actually update the child object with DML for SFDC to realize there's a change - as you have noted in your answer.